# How does webpack compute paths for async requires?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am using webpack to bundle my js but I am not sure how to specify that files included with `require.ensure` should be in the same folder as my main bundle.

Right now I have this setup in my config for output

```
output: {
    path: '',
    publicPath: '',
    filename: 'js/[name].js'
}
```

and it results in:

```
js/main.js
1.js/page2.js
```

I am unsure what is controlling the path for page2. It is being named properly based on the 3rd parameter of `ensure`, but it's in this new folder and I can't figure out why.

Comment: It is common way for chunk path generation: `[id].[module]`. You can specify `chunkFilename` in output section like this: `chunkFilename: 'js/[id].[name].js'`

Comment: oh perfect! that does exactly what I need